# how to make Multi-scale images to train the CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on Convolution Neural Network using satellite images. I want to try Multi-scale problem. Can you please suggest me how can I make the multi-scale dataset. As the input of the CNN is fixed image is fixed (e.g. 100x100)
how can the images of different scale to train the system for multi-scale problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question about YOLO9000：[Multi-Scale Training?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/darknet/multi-scale%7Csort:relevance/darknet/BP25PVj0XWA/4PpSSf11BgAJ)

Since there are only convolutional and pooling layers, so when you input multi-scale image, **the weight parameter amount is same**. Thus, multi-scale images can use a CNN model to train.

In different tasks, the methods are different. for example, in classification task, we can we can add a global pooling after the last layer; in detection task, the output is not fixed if we input multi-scale images.